# Package specific Hibernate NamingStrategy

Tags: hibernate, naming

Given several Hibernate entities in different packages of a large application, I like to make sure, that there are no naming conflicts. E.g. there could be a `Person`-Entity in package foo and another `Person`-Entity in package bar.

Now this two entities should map to table names like this:

```
foo.Person --> FOO_PERSON
bar.Person --> BAR_PERSON
```

I could use the @Table-annotation to achieve this:

```
@Table(name="FOO_PERSON")
public class Person ...

@Table(name="BAR_PERSON")
public class Person ...
```

However, I'd like to use some kind of NamingStrategy, that does this automatically. Hibernate offers the interface `org.hibernate.cfg.NamingStrategy`. I tried to extend the `DefaultNamingStrategy`, however (despite the documentation stating otherwise) you only get the unqualified name of the class and therefore no information about the package name.

There is a JIRA issue (http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4312) about this problem. Given, that it is open since 2007, I'm looking for a work-around or a totally different approach. Any ideas?

Comment: Could a custom Dialect do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

If these packages are in different project modules, you could try putting them in different schemas.  This way they table names could end up the same and you wouldn't care.  Just a thought.